# I want to add a delay when a user presses button that leads to different site, in order to add an effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my site there are three buttons ontop of eachother, on the right side, in 3 different colors.
Once a user presses one of the buttons I want a div with the color of the selected button to cover the screen from the right, and **only once that is done** I want it to redirect the user to the next site.
Does anyone have any idea of how to do this best?

I was thinking you could use js to delay the redirect whilst using standard css animations to do the visual part. Is this a good way of doing this? Does anyone know how to delay an action if a user clicks on a button?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's accept that the button is actually an anchor element (a href=..).

You can set an `eventListener` to it and when it's **clicked** use `preventDefault` to not execute it's action. There you can implement the way you want to show that animation.

You can set a second `eventListener` when the **animationEnds** and implement the behavior in that function.

More information on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Ahhh smart thank you! Good idea, I'll implement it right away!

Comment: Let me know if you require any examples or resource links added to my answer. Feel free to accept the answer if it was enough to help you solve your problem.